# Get tables with web-scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.universitego.com/bilgisayar-muhendisligi-2021-taban-puanlari-ve-basari-siralamalari/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'), 'html.parser')

for span in soup.select('tr > td:nth-child(1)'):
    print(span.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
    print('-' * 80)
```

I used the above code to get departments and tables about the department from below websites. However, I got an empty list after I run. What should I do? Thank you.

Websites
https://www.universitego.com/4-yillik-bolumlerin-2015-2016-taban-puanlari-ve-basari-siralamalari/
https://www.universitego.com/bilgisayar-muhendisligi-2021-taban-puanlari-ve-basari-siralamalari/

Comment: I assume by table you mean the list that contains all of the Acil Yardım ve Afet Yönetimi 2021 Taban Puanları values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here u go

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
r=get('https://www.universitego.com/bilgisayar-muhendisligi-2021-taban-puanlari-ve-basari-siralamalari/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='lxml')
resulting_list_of_dicts=[]
keys=soup.find('table').find('tbody').findAll('tr')[0].text.split('\n')

for values in  [i.text for i in soup.find('table').find('tbody').findAll('tr')[1:]]:
    resulting_list_of_dicts.append(dict(zip(keys,values.split('\n'))))

resulting_list_of_dicts[0]
'Üniversite Adı':'BOĞAZİÇİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ (İSTANBUL) (Devlet Üniversitesi)'
'Bölüm':'Bilgisayar Mühendisliği (İngilizce)'
'Puan Türü':'SAY'
'Kont.':'85'
'Taban Puanı':'546,34716'
'Başarı Sırası':'643'
```